# Trying to add slug to end of get_absolute_url function in models (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a function in my Post model, a get_absolute_url which is a reverse for 'post-detail', it has kwargs for primary key , how do i add another for slug; which is in my Profile model.

At the moment I'm getting error :
NoReverseMatch at /post/26/tested123/update/
Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 26}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

This error occurs when I click the update button on my update post page

feed model

feed/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

profile model
users/models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def post_detail(request, pk, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    is_liked =  Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.post = post
            data.username = user
            data.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=pk, slug=slug)
    else:
        form = NewCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'feed/post_detail.html', {'post':post, 'is_liked':is_liked, 'form':form})
```

views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['description', 'pic', 'tags']
    template_name = 'feed/create_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_name = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
        

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.user_name:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_absolute_url` in `Post` doesn't have `slug` in `kwargs` or I'm missing something? `'slug': self.user_name.profile.slug`

Comment: i thought the problem may lie with the get_absolute_url function ,as I have put slug as an argument in the views, but I'm not sure. how can i get the slug from the profile model into the get_absolute function ?

Comment: `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug': self.user_name.profile.slug})` doesn't work?

Comment: sorry,  the answer you last gave  works , I accidentally deleted a character , when trying first time . Thanks